# PHP: check if date is expired (end could be after the midnight, or no)

Tags: php

I need to check if $now (in UTC time) is before, after or between a certain interval.

So, no problem if $end is between the midnight (e.g. `$start = '18:00'` and `$end = '22:00'` ).

But after some test, I did "discover" that could be a problem if $end is after the midnight (and in my examples can be!). E.g. `$start = '20:00'` and `$end = '04:00'` . In this case, $start is in 19/09/2017 and end will be on 20/09/2017.

This is the first parts of code (some functions come from a SupportDate class myself written).

```
/**
                 * CASE #1  >>      NOW can be AFTER start and end time.
                 *              E.g.    now == 21.30 and start == 18.00 and end == 21.00
                 * 
                 * CASE #2  >>      NOW can be BEFORE start and end time.
                 *              E.g.    Now == 17.00, start == 18, end == 21.00
                 * 
                 * CASE #3  >>      NOW can be BETWEEN start and end time.
                 *              E.g.    Now == 19, start == 18, end = 21.00
                 */

                // CASE #1
                if ( ( $support->isExpired($start) === true ) && ( $support->isExpired($end) === true ) ) {

                    echo 'CASE #1 - siamo ben oltre sia l\'inizio che la fine';

                }

                // CASE #2
                if ( ( $support->isExpired($start) === false ) && ( $support->isExpired($end) === false ) ) {

                    echo 'CASE #2 - siamo ben PRIMA sia dell\'inizio che della fine';

                }

                // CASE #3
                if ( ( $support->isExpired($start) === true ) && ( $support->isExpired($end) === false ) ) {

                    echo 'CASE #3 - siamo TRA l\'inizio E la fine';

                }
```

(this is isExpired method)

```
public function isExpired($date=null,$qty=1,$interval='seconds') {

        $now = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));

        $expiry_date = new \DateTime($date, new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));

        date_add($expiry_date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($qty.' '.$interval));

        if ($now >= $expiry_date) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;
        }

    }
```

I could copy the 3 cases and apply a previous check (pseudocode: if $start > $end else .... ) and invert the check on false/true but, I think there is a better mode to get my 3 cases.

Thank you!

Comment: You should check out [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and the `between` method.

Comment: You can just use `if($start>$end)$end+=24;` and proceed normally.

Comment: @inarilo Only if $now is < than 23:59.... if $now == 23.00, you can compare if between the $start = 18:00 and $end = 03.00 (27:00 in your case). But if $now == 02:00 , $now is not between 18.00 and 27:00. I hope i'm clear...

Comment: what's the maximum time difference between start and end?

Comment: @inarilo 23 hours and 59 minutes... an entire day. can be 1 minute or 24h.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, couldn't get online. posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add timezone info, but I use the following:

```
  /**
   * @param $date       DateTime to evaluate
   * @param $dateFrom   Start DateTime
   * @param $dateTo     End DateTime
   * @return bool
   */
    public static function isDateTimeBetween($date, $dateFrom, $dateTo)
    {
        return ($date>=$dateFrom && $date<=$dateTo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic is this, the actual comparison operation may need to be adjusted if you are using datetime objects:

```
if($start > $end) return ($now >= $start || $now <= $end);
else return ($now >= $start && $now <= $end);
```

This assumes that you are using only the time data and not the date data.